# How could this question be changed to become on-topic with the same intent the OP had when posting?

Tags: discussion

I like the intention behind [Who dies from starvation?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/18426/who-dies-from-starvation?noredirect=1#comment65738_18426) but for reasons within the help center, I voted to close it as off-topic.

How could this be changed to align with the rules of Poltics.SE? as I would love to hear the expertise on the subject (without steering too much away from the original intention of the question i.e. finding out more about those whom have suffered.)

I wrote a comment:

> Of course we can, so let's say rising malnutrition is a concern of yours and you asked *"Are there any statistics to prove that under x
>   government that malnutrition has risen within families in the UK?"*
>   that would be on topic. Take a look at the meta/help center area of
>   this site for some clarification on what is on topic and what isn't.
>   That will help guide you. (This is just an example)

I still don't feel I'm 100% correct on that comment.

Comment: I agree it's an interesting question, but I can't really see a way to salvage it so that it's on-topic here. AFAIK there also isn't any other SE site where it would be on-topic.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker What about if we take away the demographic element of it and change it in regards to making it on-topic generally? (I know it steers away from the intent of both my question and the OPs, but it would be useful for me and the OP as a future reference for when asking questions, I guess?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That question is closed for being off-topic, so What you'd need is something to demonstrate that the question is actually of some notable political significance, such as if there was a political movement behind ending starvation, or that otherwise cares about starvation rates.

Comment: I think the problem here is not the significance but the vagueness of the question, e.s. it does not tie it down the the UK

Answer (score 1):

When I read the question title its a I get the impression that the person asking is not necessary seeking an answer to a political question. The first part of the question seems to be about testing a claim, the second is about getting data to check a claim. This points me to either the [1. skeptics SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) to get the claim fact checked or to [2. open data SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) to try to source the data.

A little more specific

1. Re-ask it on the [skeptics site](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/), but it would need to be phrased a little differently e.g. "Are two people per day admitted to hospital in the UK for malnutrition"
2. A person could request a data set on the [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site. The below makes me think getting a dataset might help.

> Is there any data on the gender, age, marital/family status, social status, or disability status that exists for the people who have:
>
> died been hospitalised

Not knowing alot about UK politics i'm not sure how this question could be answered on the politics site but i think the last statement could lead to something e.g. ", and if so what does it show?" which could lead to a question about demographics or potential political causes

Comment: Since when did the question title define the question as a whole? He did specify the UK in the context, you must not of read that. Your last statement simply echos what the help center says which the OP was aware of with my first comment on his question (you must not of read that either) he simply wanted to know how to reword it to have it opened again. I appreciate the reccomendations (which i feel aren't really what was asked, but hey this is meta) for the OP on the other hand.

Comment: Yep, after i reread this I answered the wrong question in the wrong place. I've still kept the general idea that the politics site may not be the best place for the answer that was being sought. As for UK in the title, you have a point, its not necessary and would only become so if that same question was being asked over and over again for different contexts. Which is unlikely unless the sight grows significantly.

Comment: Nice edit, but you have a valid point. Maybe some day we could find the correlation between these points in a political aspect, but for now I agree that the data that is wanted to be extracted is off-topic.